# how to change website width from standard size to widescreen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I understand you can set the standard size of pixels you would choose for your users to view as, but how do many websites create a "floating" screen adjustment? I'm guessing it detects which screen size the reader has, then adjusts to it. How can this be done? Info: I have the standard box size, I want to adjust it variably for "wider" laptop screens...

Comment: Responsive? Fluid System? Media Port? Google these?

Comment: Percentages and/or media queries.

Comment: thanks Christian! percentages was what I was looking for.

Comment: So does stackoverflow.com choose not to widen their screen size? (because it remains standard.) If so, why wouldn't someone want to widen?

Comment: @Pawel, perhaps because a line of text that wider than 30 words is too hard to read.

Comment: Interesting point Erno, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dustin suggests, if you want the width of an element to be relative to the available display, you can specify the width in CSS using percentages. If you want the element to "float"(in the middle), as well as maintain width relative to the display, you could try the following CSS(where myDiv is the id of of a  you want to follow this behavior):

```
div#myDiv {
    width:                  75%;
    margin-left:            auto;
    margin-right:           auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but the most basic and simple is to use a percentage for widths. Something like this and then use relative percentages for nested elements.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```